# window.onbeforeunload and redirect to root path

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, redirect, activex

I did find some javascript/activex code in a project, called when leaving a page (window.onbeforeunload):

My project is reachable at the address

```
www.someaddress.itdoesntexists/MyProjectName/page.jsp
```

When the logout function is called, the action in the page logout.jsp is correctly performed but at the end of the process the user is redirected to

```
www.someaddress.itdoesntexists
```

instead of

```
ww.someaddress.itdoesntexists/MyProjectName/
```

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loggedout = false;

bVer = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
bName = navigator.appName;
browserIE = bName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
browserNS = bName == "Netscape";

function sendHttpRequestSubmit (http_request, parameters) {
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http_request.send(parameters);
}

function httpRequest(url, mime, callback, async, parameters) {
    var http_request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType) http_request.overrideMimeType(mime);
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    if (!http_request) {
        alert('Unable to create a XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                if (callback != null) callback(http_request);
            } else alert('There is a problem with the request "' + url + '"');
        }
    }
    async = async == null ? true : async;
    http_request.open('POST', url, async);
    if (parameters != null) sendHttpRequestSubmit(http_request, parameters);
    else http_request.send(null);
    if (browserNS && !async) {//
        if (callback != null) callback(http_request);
    }
}

function logout () {
    var sg;
    if (!loggedout)
        httpRequest ("logout.jsp?js=1", "text/javascript", function (http_request) {
            sg = eval(http_request.responseText);
        }, false);
    loggedout = true;
    return sg;
}

window.onbeforeunload = logout;
```

Can someone explain to me where to tell the script that it doesn't have to go to the root path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script doesn't directly declare the redirect - it simply handles a response from an AJAX call to `logout.jsp?js=1` by evaluating it as a function - I would guess that you'll need to modify that response text (so outside of the script you've posted) to get it to redirect to the location you want.

Comment: The strange behaviour is that if I call the same logout() function from a button/link, it does bring the user to the expected path (ww.someaddress.itdoesntexists/MyProjectName/) after performing the logout process.

Comment: @GAS How are you calling the function to produce the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Well, it happens when you reload the page (F5) for example. It asks you if you want to leave the page and if so it redirects the user to the root path.

Comment: @GAS Which page? All of them or one specific page? Is it only when you refresh after already logging out? Also, could you post the response text from the AJAX call?

Comment: There is a main page that dinamically includes the other pages.
BTW, your first answer was the right one: I did redirect the response to the right location.
Thank you for your help!